# jqgrid why is my table populated but not editable?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The following code results in tables that have no editable cells. Further important info is that this is in a WordPress page template. The JavaScript files are definitely included in the page. Any idea why?

```
    var opts = {
        url:'/api1/testjson.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',width: true,
        colNames:['{Category}','{desc}', '{amount}', '{date}', '~'],
        colModel :[{name:'category', index:'category', width:50, editable:true },
                     {name:'name', index:'desc', width:50, editable:true }, 
                     {name:'color', index:'amount', width:30, editable:true }, 
                     {name:'date', index:'date', width:30, editable:true }, 
                  {name : 'end', index: 'end', width:10, formatter:'actions',
                 formatoptions: {
                     keys: true,
                     editbutton: false,
                     align: 'center',
                 delOptions: { url:'${urlDelete}', dataType: "json" }}}],
        jsonReader : {
            root:"entryData",
            page: "currentPage",
            total: "totalPages",
            records: "totalRecords",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "id"
        },      
        sortname: 'date',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 'auto',
        onSelectRow: function(id){
        },
    };



$("#jqtable1").jqGrid(opts);
opts.url = '/api1/testjson2.php';
$("#jqtable2").jqGrid(opts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to handle the rowselect event

```js
 onSelectRow: function(id){
  if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
      jQuery('#grid_id').restoreRow(lastSel); 
      lastSel=id; 
   }
   $(this).editRow(id, true);
```